# c++ private and protected member inheritance

Tags: c++, object, state, final

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Base class
class Base {
private:
    int a = 10;

public:
    void get () {
        cout << "Get:" << a << endl;
    }
};

// Derived class
class Child : public Base {
};

int main() {
    Child Childobj;
    Childobj.get();

    return 0;   
}
```

I know that the private members of the `Base` class can't be inherited but I have accessed the private member  `int a;`  with the help of the  public `get()` method.

My question is that: Does the private member of the `Base` class is sharing memory for the child object or child object just has the permission to access from the `Base` class?
In the case of public and protected, Do the protected and public members of the `Base` class share memories for the child object?

My confusion: My confusion is that I am unsure when accessing the private and protected members from the `Base` class, if the data members are being accessed and displayed from the object' memory so that I know the current state of the child object when `Child` class object is created? Thanks a lot!

Comment: All members are always inherited, if that's what you're asking. Private/protected/public only changes who can access them.

Comment: `private` members are inherited, but they are not directly accessible.   If the base class provides a `public` or `protected` member function that accesses/modifies its `private` members, then derived classes can call that member function to access/modify the `private` member, even though they cannot access it directly.

Comment: Do you mean that child's object does not share the memory of the private members? Directly accessible means private members  share memory with the child object?

Comment: Do you mean that child's object does not share the memory of the private members? Directly accessible means private members  share memory with the child object? In case of public members, the size of the child object increases which means the public members of the base class become the parts of the child object resulted in increasing the size of the child object. In the case of the private and protected, does the private and protected members share the memories for them or not??

Answer (score 0):

> I know that the private members of the Base class can't be inherited

This isn't true. All members of the base(whether private-protected-public) are inherited by the derived. *Access specifier* only affect the accessibility of the members i.e., they specify who has direct access to them.

---

> Does the private member of the Base class is sharing memory for the child object or child object just has the permission to access from the Base class?

It isn't clear what you mean by "sharing memory" here. The member function `get` is `public` which means that users of the class has direct access to `get`. Moreover `get` is also inherited by the derived class. So when you wrote `Childobj.get()` name lookup finds the inherited member `get` and uses it.